# sorting list of NavLink data

Tags: reactjs

Please tell how to sort list item text in ascending, i have bunch of List items text this is the some of list item text...please help me

Diploma Civil
                                            
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    Diploma Mining
                                            
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    Diploma Electrical
                                            
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    Diploma Mechanical

Answer (score 0):

example: I have list items as array:

```
books = ["Diploma Civil", "Diploma Mining", "Diploma Electrical", "Diploma Mechanical"]
```

and example component here:

```
function BookList({books = []}){
  return <ul>
     {books.sort().reverse().map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>}
  </ul>
}
```